# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService' in your configuration

Tags: spring-boot, activiti, java-17

I am working on Spring Activiti using Java 17 and getting this error. I have initialized and used RuntimeService in my code as follow

```
@Service
public class BPMNTaskService
{
    @Autowired
    private RuntimeService runtimeService;
    
    public String startProcess()
    {
        return runtimeService.startProcessInstanceById("queueSegregation").getActivityId();
    }
}
```

I have many articles including this [Getting started with Activiti and Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/08/getting-started-with-activiti-and-spring-boot)

And getting this error

```
Field runtimeService in com.netsol.ps.process.service.BPMNTaskService required a bean of type 'org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:

- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService' in your configuration.
```

I am using latest dependencies for all with `JDK 17` and with `Spring boot 3.0.5`. Here are the dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId> 
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId> 
    <version>3.0.7</version> 
    <type>pom</type> 
</dependency> 

<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId> 
    <version>2.6.3</version> 
</dependency> 

<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId> 
    <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId> 
    <version>6.0.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

I have already tried with the following dependencies instead of above mentioned.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${activiti.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
    <version>${activiti.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${activiti.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hmm, should be working... Please show exact steps/versions to reproduce..

Comment: Why do you need 2 versions of ```activity-spring-boot-starter-basic``` (7.2.0 and 6.0.0)? They might clash and be the reason of your error

Comment: I mistakenly added that dependency but unfortunately the error is same even after removing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the version compatibility. The most compatible versions are `JDK 17`, `Spring Boot 2.5.0` and `activiti 7.1.0.M6`. Given below are the dependencies used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${activiti.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
    <version>${activiti.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${activiti.version}</version>
</dependency>
```